# Issue with jQuery .fadeIn() queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a strange issue with jQuery and a fading loop. Let's see a bit of code (here on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4fcvze4m/1/):

```js
$('.spin-block').each(function(index) {
 $(this).delay(index * 200 + 800).fadeIn();
})
```

```css
.spin-block {
    display: none;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #a00000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="spin-block">1</div>
<div class="spin-block">2</div>
<div class="spin-block">3</div>
<div class="spin-block">4</div>
<div class="spin-block">5</div>
<div class="spin-block">6</div>
<div class="spin-block">7</div>
<div class="spin-block">8</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That's basically it.

So, sometimes (it's very random), one of this block don't show up, Mostly 5th or 6th. It can work perfectly 30 times a row and have this issue on the next refresh. I tried a workaround with this :

```
$('.spin-block')
    .each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(index * 200 + 800).fadeIn();
    })
    .promise().done(function() {
        console.log('debug');
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
```

When everything is ok, the 'debug' log show off, but when there's one missing, the console remain empty, even if next .spin-block appears. And if i force some blocks not to show, then this workaround nicely works and fade in the remaining ones (after the end of the animation, but i don't care) :

```
var i = 800;
$('.spin-block')
    .each(function() {
        i += 200;
        if (i > 1400) {
            $(this).delay(i).fadeIn();
        }
    })
    .promise().done(function() {
        console.log('debug');
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
```

There it is. Have you any idea of what's going on ? It's totally random, on any browser as far as i tested. Thank you!

---

**Please note:** This is not happening on the Fiddle I posted. I know it comes from my own JS file, but I don't have the possibility to put everything here. Besides, this is pretty much the first thing that happen in my init function.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Sorry, it didn't change anything

Comment: i refreshed a considerable amount and couldn't replicate the random issue ._. sorry gl

Comment: @GraceLee Yeah, i should have mentionned that it doesn't happen on the jsfiddle ; but i don't have the possibility to share the entire JS i'm working on. I'm going to be more precise in my post, thanks for putting this to my mind.

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of `i`? You could use `index` instead: `$('.spin-block').each(function(index, el) {
 $(this).delay(index * 200 + 800).fadeIn();
})`

Comment: Use $(element).dequeue().stop().animate('opacity',1);  or $(element).addClass('show') with a css transition timing on the element + display none, opacity 0 and .show { display:block;opacity:1 }

Comment: Is the delay meant to increase by 200ms each time? It isn't working like that?

Comment: @Ninsly That's a nice improvement, thanks, i'll use that from now on. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: @dcc I don't really understand what you mean with dequeue. I don't have the possibility to use CSS transition for this.

Comment: @thomas Yeah, the animation works. That's just one of the blocks that don't show up randomly, from time to time...

Comment: are you manipulating the div's class attribute programmatically at any point of time in your page?

Comment: @jjk_charles Yes, on click and timed events. But it's way after this first step of fadeIn().

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the issue you are facing is due to the `class` of Divs being altered dynamically during run-time and the asynchronous nature of how jQuery animations work.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fcvze4m/3/) explains the same. Essentially, it is the same set of Divs you had created initially. But instead of just animating them (iterating through $.each), I am introducing one more statement after the $.each which will remove the class associated with one of the Divs. See code below:

```
$(function () {
    $('.spin-block').each(function (index) {
        $(this).delay(index * 200 + 800).fadeIn(1000, fnCallback(index));
    });
    //Removing class dynamically for div 5 alone.
    $('.spin-block').eq(4).removeClass('spin-block');
});
```

You would expect this to animate all Divs and then removeClass from the 5th Div. But what really happens is, animation starts, simultaneously Class "spin-block" is removed from Div 5, thus blocking Div5 from being animated!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, i'll keep that in mind if needed ; but unfortunately, it seems that it's not what happen here.